# Is it possible to modify (or create) an scheduled task in Windows command-line to remove the need for user login?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to change, by using command-line, this first state in my Windows **Task Scheduler** (sorry, my Windows is in spanish; look for translation on the bottom):

[image: Scheduled task that needs user login to run]

to this other?

[image: Scheduled task with no need of user login to run]

Only change (approximate translation):

> "Run only if the user has logged in"

to

> "Run even when user has not logged in"

If modification via command-line is not possible, I could workaround by creating again the task.
I need to solve it for Windows 7, but could be useful for Windows XP too.

EDIT: The program executed is this "Prueba02.cmd":

```
echo Prueba02 >> c:\Temporal\SchedTasks\Prueba02.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a user for the task to run as.  For example `/RU system`

See `schtasks /Change /?` for more info, especially `/RU`, `/RP`, and `/NP`

Comment: Thanks, @adam, but what is `/NP`? I can not find it in the docs.

Comment: /NP A value that indicates that no password is stored. The task does not run interactively as the given user. Only local resources are available. See: http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, using the Windows utility [`Schtasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Look for the parameter `/RU`.

> `/RU username`
>
> A value that specifies the user context under which the task runs. **For the system account, valid values are**, *`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`*, or *`SYSTEM`*. For Task Scheduler 2.0 tasks, *`NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE`*, and *`NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE`* are also valid values.

Example:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "C:\MyTask.bat" /SC ONSTART /RU SYSTEM
```